# Put div on left border of other div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, show-hide

Is it possible to put the div .timedistance on the left border of the .draggable div, so that it looks like this?

[image]

Demo: http://jsbin.com/erofot/189

Code:

```
$('.draggable').hover(function(){
    $(this).find('.line').show();
                $(this).find('.timedistance').show();

}, function() {
    $(this).find('.line').hide();
      $(this).find('.timedistance').hide();


});      

      }
    });
          $(".draggable").each(function() {
   $(this).append("<div class='line'></div>");
               $(this).append("<div class='timedistance'></div>");

});
```

and CSS:

```
.line
{
  display: none;   
  width:5px; height:200px; background:#ccc;
}
.timedistance
{
  display: none;   
  width:100px; 
  height:54px;
  background:#ccc;
}
```

Comment: It's very hard to relate the image above with the example you've linked to.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to include your markup as well or probably have all of the code in jsfiddle, where the actual problem could be looked upon.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/addvF/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is:

```
margin-left: -100px;
margin-top: -54px;
```